# 3D Multidimensional Array-Initialisation of size

Tags: c, syntax

Is it possible to initialise a 3D array as follows?

```
A[ ] [ ] [3] = { { {1,2}, {3,4} }, { {5,6}, {7,8} } };
```

I wish to know for the above case which is not answered elsewhere.

Comment: My question is not answered by the above two links. I wish to know the case for 3D array. I want to know about the case which I have mentioned. The same case is not answered by the other posts.

Comment: The first link answers it just fine. No, it is not possible, because of the reasons explained in that link. It doesn't matter if you have a 2D array, a 3D array or a 42D array.